H2 Database connection fail
error image (https://i.sstatic.net/mLNGGFBD.png)
h2 database yml setting (https://i.sstatic.net/Ol0nldd1.png)
I tried to connect to h2 database from h2 console, but the error in the image occurred, and I cannot find a solution. I have test.mv.db in the path.
I can connect to h2 db with file mode, but I keep failing with server mode.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
